# I want make test class for batch apex

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, iterable

I want create test class for this batch class and when i execute with this code i got constructor() error.

> ```
> BatchMessageType myClass = new BatchMessageType();
> Id newId = Database.executeBatch(myClass);
> ```

I want to create test class for this batch apex

```
global class BatchMessageType implements Database.Batchable<solutions__MessageType__c>, Database.Stateful {

    public List<solutions__MessageType__c> parentUpdateLst = new List<solutions__MessageType__c>();
    public BatchMessageType(List<solutions__MessageType__c> parentUpdateLst){
        this.parentUpdateLst = parentUpdateLst;
    }
    global Iterable<solutions__MessageType__c> start(Database.BatchableContext info){
        return parentUpdateLst;
    }
 
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<solutions__MessageType__c> parentUpdateLst) {
        IServicesUtilConst.FROM_IOD = true;
        update parentUpdateLst;
    }  
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        // execute any post-processing operations
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a list of `solutions__MessageType__c`, and pass that in:

```
solutions__MessageType__c[] records = new solutions__MessageType__c[0];
// Add some records to the list, then...
BatchMessageType myClass = new BatchMessageType(records);
```

In general, any method you call in Apex must be given the correct number of parameters, in the correct order, with the correct data type.

Comment: let me try this way